# Python: Query Dict to JSON

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, django-views

I am trying to send some JSON to my django app in a query string by using `encodeURIComponent()` my server enpoint receives the data just fine as I can print it to the python console.

```
print request.GET
```

The output of the following line is in this format

```
<QueryDict: {u'[my json array]': [u''}}>
```

I want to convert this to JSON so I can use to get some information but I've tried using `json.loads` and other means of manipulating the data with no luck.

My output should look like this

```
[{u'something': something}, {u'something1': something2}, {u'something3': something3}]
```

Any tips as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: "I want to convert this to JSON so I can use to get some information but I've tried using json.loads". Well, there's your problem; `json.loads` takes JSON and gives you native objects; if you want to get JSON, you need `json.dumps`.

Comment: Meanwhile, how do you to get a list of dicts like your desired output when you haven't shown us any input that contains any such data? Give us a real example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) class is [a subclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1101467ce0756272a54f4c7bc65c4c335a94111b/django/http/request.py#L310) of regular Python dictionary, except that it handles multiple values for a same key (see [`MultiValueDict` implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1101467ce0756272a54f4c7bc65c4c335a94111b/django/utils/datastructures.py#L302)).

If you want to dump it to a string, just use `json.dumps()`:

```
json.dumps(my_query_dict)
```

There is also a relevant [`dict()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) method:

> QueryDict.dict()
>
> Returns dict representation of QueryDict.

Comment: Great that's exactly what I needed to understand.

Comment: This won't work if you have multiple values for a key. You even mention MultiValueDict

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

# serialize
request.session["last_get_request"] = request.GET.urlencode()

# deserialize
last_get_request = QueryDict(request.session["last_get_request"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using **Python 2.7.13** and **Django 1.11.2**.You can **get** your **data** in a **dictionary**, so that you could **access** those **data** by using their related **keys**.

```
data = json.loads(request.GET.dict().keys()[0])
```

A **block of code** inside the **function** that I used to get the **data**. **Output** is also available at bottom. This will show the **value** of parts of the above statement.

But here I am using **POST** in place of **GET** as we are are posting data to the **server**.

So the above **1 line code** is sufficient to get data as a **dictionary** in your case.

```
import json

# request.POST 
print "request.POST = ", request.POST
print type(request.POST),"\n"

# DICTIONARY
print "request.POST.dict() = ", request.POST.dict()
print type(request.POST.dict()), "\n"

# LIST ALL KEYS(here is only 1)
print "request.POST.dict().keys() = ", request.POST.dict().keys()
print type(request.POST.dict().keys()), "\n"

# UNICODE
print "request.POST.dict().keys()[0] = ", request.POST.dict().keys()[0]
print type(request.POST.dict().keys()[0]), "\n"

# GETTING THE ORIGINAL DATA(as Dictionary)
data = json.loads(request.POST.dict().keys()[0])    

# PRINTING DATA AND IT'S TYPE
print "json.loads(request.POST.dict().keys()[0]): ", data
print type(data), "\n"

# ITERATING OVER ITEMS in data dictionary
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Let's see the output,

```
request.POST = <QueryDict: {u'{"fname":"Rishikesh Agrawani","email":"rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com","contact":"7353787704","message":"Have a nice day."}': [u'']}>
<class 'django.http.request.QueryDict'> 

request.POST.dict() =  {u'{"fname":"Rishikesh Agrawani","email":"rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com","contact":"7353787704","message":"Have a nice day."}': u''}
<type 'dict'> 

request.POST.dict().keys() =  [u'{"fname":"Rishikesh Agrawani","email":"rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com","contact":"7353787704","message":"Have a nice day."}']
<type 'list'> 

request.POST.dict().keys()[0] =  {"fname":"Rishikesh Agrawani","email":"rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com","contact":"7353787704","message":"Have a nice day."}
<type 'unicode'> 

json.loads(request.POST.dict().keys()[0]):  {u'message': u'Have a nice day.', u'contact': u'7353787704', u'email': u'rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com', u'fname': u'Rishikesh Agrawani'}
<type 'dict'> 

message Have a nice day.
contact 7353787704
email rishikesh0014051992@gmail.com
fname Rishikesh Agrawani
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle multi values, you can do the following:

```
json.dumps({k: d.getlist(k) for k in d.keys()})
```

or use join for compactness:

```
json.dumps({k: ",".join(d.getlist(k)) for k in d.keys()})
```

or check if this is multi value, and only then show as list

```
 json.dumps({k: (d.getlist(k) if len(d.getlist(k)) > 1 else d[k]) for k in d.keys()})
```