# Return QuerySet as JSON?

Tags: json, django

I'm working in Django 1.8 and having trouble finding the modern way to do this.

This is what I've got, based on Googling and [this blog post](http://www.leemckinnon.com/example-of-returning-a-django-queryset-as-json-response/):

```
results = PCT.objects.filter(code__startswith='a')
json_res = []
for result in results:
    json_res.append(result.as_dict())
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_res), content_type='application/json')
```

However this gives me `'PCT' object has no attribute 'as_dict'`.

Surely there must be a neater way by now?

I was wondering if it was possible to use [JSONResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) but frustratingly, the docs give no example of how to use JSONRespose with a queryset, which must be the most common use case. I have tried this:

```
results = PCT.objects.filter(code__startswith='a')
return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```

This gives `[<PCT: PCT object>, <PCT: PCT object>] is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a JSON response using Django and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python)

Comment: but *surely* things must have got simpler since 2010?

Comment: They surely have, and it's referenced in the first answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: ok, so that links to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428092/creating-a-json-response-using-django-and-python/24411716#24411716 which shows how to return a dictionary using JSONResponse. But I have a QuerySet, not a dictionary. I'm trying `return JsonResponse(results.values(), safe=False)` but that gives me a `TypeError: not JSON serializable`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm really not trying to be difficult, but this does seem like one of the most common things one might want to do in Django, given the move to front-end apps: I'm surprised it's so difficult to figure out how to do it.

Comment: If all you want to do is return the result of a model-query as part of a GET, then this sounds like a REST-compatible call. Did you have a look at the [REST-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)?

Comment: @mknecht looks like I may have to use that if this is impossible, but seems a bit heavyweight - I just want a simple JSON method that I can use for an autocomplete field, not a full RESTful API.

Comment: I really don't think this question is a duplicate: the "duplicate" is ancient, and yes it has a recent update, but the update is about converting a dictionary to JSON, not a QuerySet, so that's quite different.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26373992

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simplest solution without any additional framework:

```
results = PCT.objects.filter(code__startswith='a').values('id', 'name')
return JsonResponse({'results': list(results)})
```

returns `{'results': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, ...]}`

or if you only need the values:

```
results = PCT.objects.filter(code__startswith='a').values_list('id', 'name')
return JsonResponse({'results': list(results)})
```

returns `{'results': [[1, 'foo'], ...]}`

Comment: So close! But the first snippet gives me the following error message: `[{'code': u'5M1', 'name': u'South Birmingham'}, {'code': u'5M3', 'name': u'Walsall Teaching'}`] is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me :( I get a `<PCT: PCT object> is not JSON serializable` with `return JsonResponse({'results': list(results)})`

Answer (score 5):

use values() to return a querydict, and pass that to json.dumps

```
values = PCT.objects.filter(code__startswith='a').values()
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(values), content_type='application/json')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: Thansk, but same problem as with other answers: `TypeError... is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: strange, it should  work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798395/python-query-dict-to-json. Maybe try calling the dict() method on values.

Answer (score 4):

Most of these answers are out of date. Here's what I use:

**views.py (returns HTML)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core import serializers

def your_view(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', YourModel.objects.all())
    context = {"data":data}
    return render(request, "your_view.html", context)
```

**views.py (returns JSON)**

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def your_view(request):
    data = serializers.serialize('json', YourModel.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Django's serialization framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/). It allows not only the XML format, but also JSON and YAML.

Comment: Thanks, having read through that page I've got as far as `data = serializers.serialize("json", results)` and then `return data` but that gives me an error message about Unicode. Is there a missing step?

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30243413), using `JsonResponse`, is nice and simple. However, it does not return complete objects.

An alternative is to use Django's [`serializers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/). Here's an example copied verbatim from the [admin actions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages):

> ```py
> ...
>    response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/json")
>    serializers.serialize("json", queryset, stream=response)
>    return response
> ```

This is very similar to what happens in Django's [`JsonResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), as can be seen in the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).

The main difference is that `JsonResponse` calls `json.dumps()` directly, and does not know how to handle querysets, whereas the example above uses `serializers.serialize('json', ...)`, which [does know how to handle querysets](https://github.com/django/django/blob/39f83765e12b0e5d260b7939fc3fe281d879b279/django/core/serializers/json.py#L54), and returns complete objects that can also be de-serialized later on.

If you want to save directly to file (using `content-disposition: attachment` to open a save dialog in the browser), you could use a [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects), for example:

```py
...
    data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
    return FileResponse(
        io.BytesIO(data.encode('utf-8')),
        content_type='application/json',
        as_attachment=True,
        filename=f'{queryset.model.__name__.lower()}-objects.json'
    )
```