# Urlencoded data to Python dict or JSON

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I got data from service in format, that I never used before. As I understand, it's a urlencoded dict. During web search I found a lot examples, how to convert data from dict to urlencoded format. But can't find, how to get proper JSON data format FROM urlencoded.

Can someone show me example, how to "convert" data below to proper JSON or Python Dict format?

```
{'leads[status][0][id]': ['8141383'], 'leads[status][0][name]': ['Item 01'], 'leads[status][0][status_id]': ['33687112'], 'leads[status][0][old_status_id]': ['33482677'], 'leads[status][0][price]': ['980'], 'leads[status][0][responsible_user_id]': ['6097627'], 'leads[status][0][last_modified]': ['1594816180'], 'leads[status][0][modified_user_id]': ['6097627'], 'leads[status][0][created_user_id]': ['6097627'], 'leads[status][0][date_create]': ['1594641770'], 'leads[status][0][pipeline_id]': ['3336151'], 'leads[status][0][account_id]': ['28926364'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][0][id]': ['340737'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][0][name]': ['ID заказа'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][0][values][0][value]': ['cef6941b-eb13-4b79-8d3d-0a4c0b4a4954'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][1][id]': ['340751'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][1][name]': ['Program ID'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][1][values][0][value]': ['5316b07c-c554-4fc1-9010-a757db28b264'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][2][id]': ['336313'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][2][name]': ['Program'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][2][values][0][value]': ['Item 01'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][3][id]': ['336315'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][3][name]': ['count'], 'leads[status][0][custom_fields][3][values][0][value]': ['2'], 'leads[status][0][created_at]': ['1594641770'], 'leads[status][0][updated_at]': ['1594816180']}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Query Dict to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798395/python-query-dict-to-json)

Comment: I didn't see any mention of a problem with querydict in my question. If you convert data example from qdict to dict, it doesn't give you proper structure

Comment: Your pre-edit question contained the example as a QueryDict. However, as you've changed it, the sample is a proper Python dict. It has keys and values, albeit the keys are string representations of dictionary access statements. If you are looking to convert the keys into the dictionary structure they represent, that is a different question than the one you've expressed here.